# SQL query to select only rows with unique set of 3 columns but with non-unique subset of 2 columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

*I first posted this question on Code Review but it was deemed off-topic there since it represents a [simplified extract and not the actual project](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652). Apparently MCVE is not sufficient there.*

I'm building a SQL query for the following (simplified) table:

```
ID Key1 Key2 Value Something
----------------------------
1  10   100   v1    aaa
2  10   100   v2    bbb
3  11   111   v3    ccc
4  10   100   v1    ddd  
5  10   100   v1    eee
6  11   111   v2    fff
8  12   222   v0    ggg
```

In the result I need to include rows that in the original table itself satisfy the following 2 filtering conditions:

1. Combinations of (`key1, key2, value`) are **unique**
2. Combinations of (`key1, key2`) are **not unique**

So the result should be:

```
ID Key1 Key2 Value Something
----------------------------
2  10   100   v2    bbb
3  11   111   v3    ccc
6  11   111   v2    fff
```

I (seemingly) have a solution with 2 joins with aggregated derived tables.

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM Table_3 t0
JOIN
    (SELECT key1, key2
     FROM Table_3 
     GROUP BY key1, key2
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t1 ON t0.key1 = t1.key1 
                             AND t0.key2 = t1.key2 
JOIN  
    (SELECT key1, key2, value
     FROM Table_3 
     GROUP BY key1, key2, value
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) t2 ON t0.key1 = t2.key1 
                             AND t0.key2 = t2.key2 
                             AND t0.value = t2.value
```

Can the code be simplified? Possibly with windowing functions?

Here is [**Fiddle** for SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/25104f/5)

The real project will be in BigQuery

*Note*: field `something` (which represents multiple fields in real table) must be a part of the result.

Comment: and why not line 8?

Comment: @nbk In `8` the combination of `key1` and `key2` is ***unique*** so it violates 2nd condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from Table_3
qualify count(1)over(partition by key1, key2, value)=1
        and count(1)over(partition by key1, key2)>1
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of [qualify clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this SQL code can be simplified using window functions. Here's the simplified query:

```
SELECT key1, key2, value
FROM (
  SELECT key1, key2, value, 
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2) AS cnt1, 
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2, value) AS cnt2
  FROM Table_3
) t
WHERE cnt1 > 1 AND cnt2 = 1
```

This query uses two window functions to count the occurrences of each combination of keys and each combination of keys and values. Then, it selects the rows where the count of the key combination is greater than 1 and the count of the key-value combination is exactly 1. This effectively filters out all rows that appear multiple times with the same key combination, and selects the unique rows that appear only once with a given key combination.

Comment: @pm-77-1 mentionned for my (2nd) solution (only), that he requires all colums of the table so I adapted it. Here, this is missing. The adapted/updated version I added as third solution in my answer, referencing the origin author :-).

Answer (score 0):

In my view with CTEs, this is simpler - but I do not know if it serves you for BigQuery:

```
WITH notUnique2 as (
  SELECT key1, key2
      FROM Table_3 
      GROUP BY key1, key2
      HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 
), unique3 as (
  SELECT key1, key2, value
      FROM Table_3 
      GROUP BY key1, key2, value
      HAVING COUNT(1) = 1 
)
SELECT u3.*
FROM unique3 u3
JOIN notUnique2 nu2
ON u3.key1 = nu2.key1 and u3.key2 = nu2.key2;
```

And another solution - edited after comment from asker:

```
SELECT r.* FROM Table_3 r JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT a.key1, a.key2, a.value
      FROM Table_3 a
      LEFT JOIN Table_3 b -- for uniqueness
          ON a.ID != b.ID -- not itself
              AND a.key1 = b.key1
              AND a.key2 = b.key2
              AND a.value = b.value
      JOIN Table_3 c -- join proves not uniqueness of key1, key2
          ON a.ID != c.ID -- not itself
              AND a.key1 = c.key1
              AND a.key2 = c.key2       
  WHERE 1=1
      AND b.ID IS NULL -- uniqueness
) i
ON i.key1 = r.key1
AND i.key2 = r.key2
AND i.value = r.value;
```

**@Абай Саякбаев's solution completed** - asker demanded full row in result:

```
WITH counted as (
   SELECT key1, key2, value, 
         COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2) AS cnt1, 
         COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2, value) AS cnt2
   FROM Table_3
), alternativeKey as (
  SELECT key1, key2, value
  FROM counted 
  WHERE cnt1 > 1 AND cnt2 = 1
)
SELECT r.* 
FROM Table_3 r
JOIN alternativeKey a
ON a.key1 = r.key1
AND a.key2 = r.key2
AND a.value = r.value;
```

Comment: BigQuery supports CTE.

Comment: I need **full** rows from the table. That's why I added field `something`.

Comment: I updated the 2nd solution - here with a join - could be done as well with CTE.